# Batch force close window

Tags: batch-file

How do I make a batch file close.

say if I had this code:

```
@echo off
goto loop
[exit command]
:loop
```

How would I make the batch file close its window. [exit command] would be the command that would make it exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are a fiew ways of doing this. The first one is this:

```
goto :eof
```

This sends the script to the end of the file so forth making it close.

```
EXIT
```

This is the most simple one just a simple exit.

For more information see this http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to close the window, then use `exit`. However, this will affect a normal session as well, i.e. if you start `cmd` and run the batch file it will close your session.

If you merely want to exit the *batch file* (which will close the window if you started it via double-click), then you can use either one of

```
goto :eof
exit /b
```